# Could I have some help solving this conditional probability problem?

Tags: probability

The probability of event $A$ occurring is $P(A)=13/25$.The probability of event B acquiring is $P(B) = 9/25$.  The conditional probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ has occurred is $P(A|B) = 5/9$

(a) Determine the following probabilities

i - $P( A$ and $B)$

ii - $P(B|A)$

iii- $P(A$ or $B$ or both)

iv- P(Not A | Not B)

(b) Determine $P( A$ occurs or $B$ does not occur), show your working

I have done the first $3$ parts of the question $18$ (a(i-iii)) but at fourth part of a and part $b$, I wasn't sure how to work it out

The answers are:

ai- $1/5$

aii- $5/13$

aiii- $17/25$

aiv- $1/2$

b-$21/25$

This is an a level question and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for a) iv:

$$
P(A^c \mid B^c) = \frac{ P(A^c \cap B^c) }{P(B^c)} = \frac{P( (A \cup B)^c )}{P (B^c)}
$$

Hint for b):
$$
P(A \cup B^c) = P(A) + P(B^c) - P(A \cap B^c)
$$
For that last intersection you can apply the rule that
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A \mid B)P(B)
$$
and then look back at a) iv

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it go

Comment: I have the answer part a iv , thanks. Still can't get part b as my value for P(A and NotB) seems wrong. I keep getting 8/25. Could I get a bit more help?

Comment: Never mind got it, thanks for all the help

Comment: @NikhilPatel glad to help. Remember to mark answers as accepted if you're satisfied.